# gmcs and smcs are missing on Mono for Windows 64-bit

Tags: mono

The `gmcs` and `smcs` executables appear to be missing from `C:\Program Files\Mono\bin` after installing [Mono 64-bit](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-win).  Can anybody tell me why this is, or where to get them?

Edit: they are also missing on Debian

Comment: Those are "ancient" and wrappers for `msc`, and `msc` was replaced by the  roselyn-based `csc`

Comment: I'm trying to compile `libcommon` which utilizes `gmcs`.  IMO they should still be shipped with mono as wrappers around `mcs`, `csc`, or whatever the latest compiler is.  (Unless there are breaking changes in the accepted flags and options?)

Comment: Install an older /matching version of Mono then

Comment: “IMO they should still” is subjective. Showing a clear error can easily draw attention, while hiding the potential issues can end up with more unhappiness.

Comment: They should display a warning that the command is deprecated.  What Mono has here is a breaking change.

Comment: Like dmcs does.